# J query datatables destroy and re-create

Tags: jquery, html, database

here i have to destroy and recreate the table but I am not geeting where i am wrong please help me where in am wrong.
  This is function i have used to destroy and recreate

```
function destroyTableCreateAgain(){
    if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#data') ) {
        $(function(){
            $('#data').DataTable({
                "destroy": true,
                "columnDefs": [ {
                    "targets": 'no-sort',
                    "orderable": false,
                }]
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why you made the function so complex?

Comment: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51203748/edit) your question and provide further details on what exactly are you trying to achieve. According to your comment below: "sorry the question is wrong i want to how to destroy and recreate jquery datatable" - your question does not show enough details.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function, it will work. In your current code, you wrapped a function inside `$`, I don't see it's being executed.

```
function destroyTableCreateAgain() {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#data')) {
        $('#data').DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 'no-sort',
                "orderable": false,
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry the question is wrong i want to how to destroy and recreate jquery datatable

Comment: if you put an alert inside the `if` condition, you can come to know the code being executed or not. if you can't see the alert, that means the datatable is not initialized with the `$("#data")` element.